# ASP if statements and while loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I've noticed that you can set javascript variables using ASP code. For example:

```
var test = "<%response.write(number)%>"
```

I was wondering if other types of ASP code can work in javascript, such as if statements or while loops. For Example:

```
function test1()
{
   count = 0;
   <%if number = 1 then%>
        count = count + 1;
   <%end if%>
}

function test2()
{
   count = 0;
   <%index = 0
   do while index < 10 %>
       count = count +1;
   <%index = index +1
   loop%>
}
```

I am relatively new to web development and programming so I'm not sure if this is possible. If this does not work, is there any way I can get around this or a different way to code it?

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really need to understand the difference between `client-side` processing and `server-side` processing... they achieve two quite different things

Comment: Server side - ASP, PHP and similar, this code is "compiled" by the web server before it gives the user the webpage, so things like asp variables are set at this point. Client side - Javascript, this retrieves the web page as the server sent it and then manipulates it, so yes, you can set javascript variables with ASP

Comment: Sorry @user1538100, but that is not entirely correct... not all server-side is compiled (ASP.NET markup for instance), but it **is** processed on the server

Comment: Used compiled in quote marks as I couldn't think of the proper word (as you put it, processed) apologies x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I say in my comment, it's really important to understand the difference between client-side and server-side processing in things like ASP, ASP.NET, PHP, etc.

As you appear to know, the javascript is run on the client-side (i.e. the browser).  The server-side does processing of the ASP, ASP.NET, PHP, etc and then sends information (HTML, Javascript, etc) to the browser.

You can indeed do the following code that you have written...

```
function test2()
{
   count = 0;
   <%index = 0
   do while index < 10 %>
       count = count +1;
   <%index = index +1
   loop%>
}
```

But instead of the SERVER doing the *calculation* 10 times, the server will *create* the line 10 times and send it to the browser...

```
function test2()
{
   count = 0;
       count = count +1;
       count = count +1;
       ... followed by another 8 lines of the same
}
```

... meaning the CLIENT run javascript will do the calculation 10 times.

Depending on exactly what you need the code to do will depend on whether the code should be run client-side or server-side... it's pretty much impossible to tell you which without knowing what you're trying to do.

Hope this helps

Comment: I see. This helps out a lot. Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: You're welcome @blazinazian - client-side vs server-side can take a bit of getting your head around! Good luck with the rest of your project

Comment: Is it possible for me to send you a copy of what I have now? Because the concept is there, but nothing is happening and I'm wondering if I'm getting client-side vs server-side mixed up again.

Comment: Of course @blazinazian, the best thing to do would be to chat, but I'm trying to work out how to initiate it (before it's suggested due to too many comments)

Comment: Ok. Please let me know when the chat has been initiated.

Comment: @blazinazian, did you have any luck after our chat yesterday? Would be interested to hear your progress

Comment: Yes, I've made much progress after our chat. Firebug really saved my hide on multiple occasions. If I didn't have it, I would probably still be banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why my javascript code was not working. A problem has come up today and I'm not sure how to resolve it. I'm trying to see if a certain checkbox is checked and I am stepping through my code in Firebug. However, if the checkbox is unchecked, then it skips the rest of the javascript code. Any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: Hi @blazinazian. Does it return into the calling function? Normally the cause of javascript just crapping out on you is a fault in the code or something like a null exception... check the console window for any errors

Comment: Other than the "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared." error, there are no other errors in the console window. It may be a null exception, though. Do you know what value getElementById().checked returns if it is unchecked?

Comment: @blazinazian, as long as `getElementById()` returns a checkbox (or radio) control, `.checked` should simply be a boolean value

Comment: Hmm, that's odd then. I keep on trying to step through the code. But everytime it hits the unchecked checkbox, firebug show an onclick() event, which I assume is returning into the calling function. Really not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @blazinaziano, other than putting the result of the `getElementById()` into a variable, and then on the next line checking the `.checked` on that variable (and if you haven't noticed you can add new "watches" in the tab, to check individual things like the return value), I really can't give you any more idea - sorry!

Comment: No problem. You've helped me out more than enough by introducing me to Firebug and answering my questions. Thank you very much!